# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) on project

Tags: maven, netbeans

I'm new to this. The computer I am using is an M1 Macbook. The IDE I am using is Netbeans.

Im getting an error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) on project ParklandPreschoolProject: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null

I have tried to clear the repository from m2/repository as a solution but with no success in solving the issue.

Here's my pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParklandPreschoolProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ParklandPreschoolProject</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-rev-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Which JDK do you use? An API compatibilty issue can not being solved by deleting the cache...

Comment: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4, Java: 16.0.2 and Maven 2.5. I assume I need to update Maven? If you can kindly point me in the direction of where the update feature is on netbeans. Thanks for going easy on me.

Comment: Maven 2.5 does not exist... the question is which Maven verision. Can be identified by `mvn --version` ...

Comment: The existing versions can be checked here: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html